# VBA Sizing an Array with User Choosing its Size

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a string array of keywords. The string array will have a set number of columns (various number of keywords for 3 different fruits: apple, banana, orange). However, the column for each row will be a different size based on how many keywords the user is looking for, for EACH fruit. The user may be looking for 1 keyword for apple, 2 keywords for banana, and 3 keywords for orange. when it's all said and done, I want a string array of 3xC, where C is the largest number of keywords, and the unfilled cells are empty. Here is the code I have so far, but I am unsure of how to dimensionalize the array.

```
Public strTemp(0 To 2, 0 To 100) As Variant
Sub GetKeyWords()

Dim numKeyA As Integer
Dim numKeyB As Integer
Dim numKeyO As Integer



'Ask user for integer value of keywords looking for
numKeyA = InputBox("How many keywords would you like to search for the A? (Integer)", "A Integer Value Please")

'Ask user for the specific keywords
For k = 1 To numKeyA

    'Save keywords into strTemp array
    strTemp(0, k - 1) = InputBox("Please enter keyword" & k)

Next

numKeyB = InputBox("How many keywords would you like to search for the B? (Integer)", "B Integer Value Please")

For a = 1 To numKeyB

    'Save keywords into strTemp array
    strTemp(1, a - 1) = InputBox("Please enter keyword" & a)

Next

numKeyC = InputBox("How many keywords would you like to search for the C? (Integer)", "C Integer Value Please")

For b = 1 To numKey777

    'Save keywords into strTemp array
    strTemp(2, b - 1) = InputBox("Please enter keyword" & b)



    maxColumn = WorksheetFunction.Max(numKeyA, numKeyB, numKeyC)
    ReDim strTemp(2, maxColumn)



Next


End Sub
```

The way the code is right now, I get an error when trying to redim the array at the end to size it based on the largest column. If I don't size the code at the beggining, I get an error "subscript out of range" for strTemp(0, k-1) = InputBox("please enter keyword" & k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public strTemp() As Variant
```

Leave out the indices in the declaration.  Then you do need to `ReDim` before you try to put anything in `strTemp`.  If you do all three `InputBox`es first, you'll be able to size `strTemp` and then read in the keywords.

Alternatively, use

```
ReDim strTemp(2, numKeyA)
```

after the first `InputBox`, then say

```
ReDim Preserve strTemp(2, IIf(numKeyA>numKeyB, numKeyA, numKeyB))
```

after the second `InputBox` (the `IIf` is so you don't shrink the array).  `Preserve` will keep values that are already there.  Similarly, after the third InputBox,

```
ReDim Preserve strTemp(2, maxColumn)
```

Comment: Thank you! This almost works! When I put all the same amount of keywords for each fruit (3), the first two keywords for the apple disappear so my array looks like this: ['', '', c; a, b, c; a, b, c], do you know why this is?

I was wondering what the IIf(numKeyA > numKeyB, numKeyA, numKeyB) did exactly, maybe it has something to do this with line?

Comment: @A.Cod Not sure.  **(1)** The `IIf()` is the same as `max(numKeyA,numKeyB)`.  **(2)** In the line `For b = 1 To numKey777`, should that be `1 To numKeyC`?  **(3)** If you haven't already, add `Option Explicit` and `Option Base 0` to the top of your module and compile to see if that flags any errors.  **(4)** The `Redim` statements should be outside the `For` loops, and I just noticed in your original code that was not the case.  The order is `InputBox` for bounds, `Redim`, `For` loop for values, repeated three times.

Comment: it's because the ReDim was inside the loop! Thanks a ton. Just one thing that needs to be debugged. When I go from 1 keywords for Apple, to 3 keywords for Banana, i get a subscript out of range error after typing in the 3rd keyword for banana. the error occurs on the line: strTemp(1, a-1) = InputBox("please enter keyword" & a)

Comment: @A.Cod Not sure off-hand.  Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38272885/edit) to include your code as it stands now, after the code you already have (so people reading this later understand the original context).  I'll take a look at it tomorrow when I get back to my computer, or maybe someone else will have an idea.  In the meantime, stick breakpoints on the `Redim` statements and use the `Watch` window to see how the dimensions of `strTemp` change each time.  That should give you some clues.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for helping. I ended up getting rid of the IIf(numKeyA>numKeyB, numKeyA, numKeyB)) and just found the max of that and resizing based on MaxColumn and it worked.

Comment: @A.Cod Good news - glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
Refer comments for details.

```
   Sub test()

    Dim lCtrCol_New     As Long
    Dim lCtrRow_New     As Long
    Dim lInst           As Long
    Dim arrNew()



    '/ Start New Array
    ReDim arrNew(1 To 3, 1 To 1)

    '/ Add Values
    arrNew(1, 1) = "Apple"
    arrNew(2, 1) = "Orange"
    arrNew(3, 1) = "Tomato"

    '/ Loop and assign unique values
    For lCtrRow_New = LBound(arrNew) To UBound(arrNew)
      lInst = Val(InputBox("No. of Keywords for " & arrNew(lCtrRow_New, 1), ""))
                If lInst + 1 > UBound(arrNew, 2) Then
                    ReDim Preserve arrNew(1 To 3, 1 To lInst + 1)
                End If

                For lCtrCol_New = LBound(arrNew, 2) To lInst
                    arrNew(lCtrRow_New, lCtrCol_New + 1) = InputBox("Please enter keyword #" & lCtrCol_New & " for " & arrNew(lCtrRow_New, 1))
                Next

       Next
End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work the way i want it to. When I run this code it asks for number of keywords for apple so i put 1, then it asks for keywords for orange so i put 1 then it asks keyword for tomato and i put 1, then it never asks for the keywords, it just stops running.

Comment: edited the answer. never tested for #1 keyword. Try now.

Comment: awesome! found a few bugs however. If you say you want 3 keywords for apple, it asks you for 3 keywords for the 2 other fruits even though you put different numbers for the other two (eg, 2 keywords for banana, 1 for tomato)